# SQL Server find closest match string and insert into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a string (`varchar(6)`) with a postalcode (e.g. 1234AB).
I want to calculate the distance between two postalcodes, but only the ones that are the closest to each other.
So, I want an update statement that is like this (PSEUDO CODE):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET COL2 WHERE SAME ROW COL1 IS CLOSEST MATCH

COL1   | COL2
1111AA | CLOSEST MATCH FROM COL1 (The closest match for 1111AA in the COL1 column, in this case 1111AB)
1111AB | CLOSEST MATCH FROM COL1
1112AA | CLOSEST MATCH FROM COL1
```

Result could me something like this:

```
COL1   | COL2
1111AA | 1111AB
1111AB | 1111AA
1111BB | 1111AB (or maybe 1111BC)
```

## UPDATE

The other thing which would work for me is grabbing the even rows and transfer them to `COL2` so you would get something like this:

```
COL1  | COL2
1111AA| 1111AB
1111BB| 1111BC
```

So, I want to ORDER BY `COL1` and then grab the even rownumbers and TRANSFER (not copy) them to `COL2`.

I hope it is clear what I want. I couldn't find my specific needs on the internet, that's why I asked it here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you define as 'closest match', anything that matches a certain number of characters (should they match in sequence or anywhere in the text), that sounds the same or that is distance based close? You will need to define that before being able to determine what algorithm you will need for your select statement.

Comment: How do you tell which postal codes are closest? Why would `1111AA` be closer to `1111AB` than `1111AC` ? Bear in mind that postal codes usually represent a polygon (or sometimes a point) and might have several "closest" neighbors. Sometimes a postal code don't represent a physical point at all, but rather a logical entity.

Comment: @BerndLinde I do not know really, but I think my question isn't properly asked. Could you please look at the 'UPDATE' part?

Comment: @jpw I do not know really, but I think my question isn't properly asked. Could you please look at the 'UPDATE' part?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function to calculate the distance of two postal codes, let's call it `distance(p1,p2)`.

Then you can  filter the closest postal code by cross join all postal codes and rank the distance of each combination of two postal codes.

```
;WITH  TEMP AS (
SELECT T1.POSTCODE AS COL1, 
       T2.POSTCODE AS COL2,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.POSTCODE ORDER BY DISTANCE(T1.POSTCODE,T2.POSTCODE)) AS RANK
  FROM MYTABLE AS T1
 CROSS JOIN MYTABLE AS T2)
SELECT COL1,COL2
  FROM TEMP
 WHERE RANK=1
```